# after running code for sometime macro unable to set htmldiv

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have this code to scrape product images URL from amazon.
This code is working for up to approx 500 URL scrape but after that, it stops working. the reason is `htmldiv` is not set for some reason. I need to wait for about 1 hour before it starts working again or some time it starts working after restarting the PC.

Rng is the list of urls from where I am **scraping** product images url (amazon)

VBA code:

```vb
Sub scrapeimgs2()
    'On Error Resume Next
    Dim XMLRequest As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLDiv As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim cel, rng As Range
  
    Set rng = Sheets("sheet1").Range("i2:i1312")
    For Each cel In rng
        Application.StatusBar = cel.Row
        XMLRequest.Open "GET", cel, False
        XMLRequest.send
        
        If XMLRequest.Status <> 200 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("O" & cel.Row) = "Err"
        Else
            HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLRequest.responseText
            Set HTMLDiv = HTMLDoc.getElementById("landingImage") '<this line is set to nothing after scrapping approx 500urls>
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("O" & cel.Row) = HTMLDiv.getAttribute("src", 0)
        End If

        If cel.Row Mod 50 = 0 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Save
        End If
        HTMLDoc.Close
        Set HTMLDiv = Nothing
    Next cel
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably because Amazon does not allow automatic scraping of their website. They detect it, flag you as BOT and block you, because you are not allowed to web scrape Amazon.

Comment: good. that's means i need a VPN which changes ip just before hitting the max scrapping limit

Comment: No, you need to stop violating their rules and terms. You probably won't get any assistance here to violate their rules.